# How to access edge://flags (need to enable Chromecast support in Edge)

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromecast

I need to cast a video content from Chromium Edge (Chrome 64, Edge 17.17134) to my Chromecast. The browser is running under Windows 10 Home. The Chromecast is setup and working well with other Android devices. But in the Edge browser, the chromecast is not detected.

According to this article - https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/enable-chromecast-support-in-chromium-edge-windows-10/ - it's necessary to tweak some flags on the `edge://flags` page. The problem is that I can not access this page. When I type `edge://flags` in the address bar, the browser starts searching the text in the default search engine. I did not find any way to disable the smart searching feature. According to Microsoft docs, it looks like there is no way to disable searching from the address bar, user can only change default engine. BTW I did switch off the option "Show search suggestions as I type" already - it does not help. Some people suggest to use group policy editor to disable the feature (see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/address-bar-settings-gp)), but Windows 10 Home does not have the editor.

So the questions are:

- what can be a problem with chromecast not detected by Chromium/Edge (if it's not actually the "secret" flags)?
- is there a way to open `edge://flags` page without dealing with group policies?

Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Try `about:flags` and see [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/66419-enable-disable-about-flags-page-microsoft-edge.html) if problem.

Comment: Alternative: Install Google Chrome Browser, here is all instructions to make it all work in 5-10 minutes. https://www.techbout.com/setup-chromecast-on-windows-10-computer-25102/

Comment: @harrymc, `about:flags` do work, but the page does not contain required flags related to casting.

Comment: Funny questions: Have you tried `Chrome://flags`? Or do you have in the three-points menu the option of "More Tools > Cast Media to Device"?

Answer (score -1):

**Easy**

1) Press *Windows key*

2) type

```
run
```

3) Press *enter*

4) type

```
regedit
```

5) Press *enter*

6) Go to this key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Main
```

7) This file

```
PreventAccessToAboutFlagsInMicrosoftEdge
```

8) Change value to

```
0
```

This will allow you to [access flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/developer-settings-gp)

The flag page is

```
about:flags
```

Comment: `about:flags` works as is, but there is no `#load-media-router-component-extension` there. I suppose `about:flags` are not the same as suggested `edge://flags`.

Comment: Your request was to access the flags page, what is your next request?

Comment: My request was about `edge://flags` because it seems different to `about:flags`. The actual task is to access media router component, which is not mentioned on `about:flags`.

Comment: Have you tried an extra / after flags. Try this edge://flags/ If I had windows 10 running on would just write some code to do it all for you. Could you please press the up arrow on my answer for trying?

Answer (score -1):

Just install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) on your *Chromium Edge (Chrome 64, Edge 17.17134)*

Then follow these [STEPS](https://www.techbout.com/setup-chromecast-on-windows-10-computer-25102/)

Comment: I have the chromecast device already setup, whereas the steps seem appropriate to installation from scratch - I don't want to break existing environment. Of course, I took the note about standalone Chrome, but this would be the last resort.